# Xcode 13.1 muestra el código fuente de los .framework

Tags: ios, xcode, framework

Quiero ocultar el código fuente del framework cuando desde la App haces "cmd + click + jump to definition"

¿Alguna configuración en "Build settings" para ocultarlo?

Con Xcode 11.3.1 funciona correctamente, desde la app solo muestra los prototipos de los métodos públicos pero en Xcode 13 muestra todo el código fuente.

Xcode 11.3.1

```
public class Operation {
    public static func plus(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int
}
```

Xcode 13.1

```
public class Operation {
        public static func plus(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
            return a + b
        }
    }
```

Comment: Compilaste el framework como `XCFramework`? [Link](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev544efab96)

Comment: Si, pero mi framework contiene otros frameworks, y los XCFrameworks no pueden contener otros frameworks, corrígeme si estoy equivocado.

Comment: Si todo está en un solo proyecto de tipo `Framework` creería que puedes compilarlo con la línea de código del link en la terminal.

Comment: Si, es un proyecto de tipo Framework pero no consigo ocultar la implementación, el mismo proyecto desde una versión anterior de Xcode si la oculta

Comment: utiliza un `protocol` solo expones el protocolo

Answer (score 0):

La única forma que he encontrado de ocultar el código es generando un xcframework como indican en el primer comentario a la pregunta, pero hay que generar un xcframework por cada uno de los frameworks, donde el framework principal contiene los sub-xcframeworks indicando "Do not Embed", así pueden ser usados para crear este framework principal.

A la hora de distribuir, se tienen que distribuir los tres xcframeworks, es decir el principal y los dos sub-xcframeworks, donde la app que los integre debe de indicar "Embeb and Sign".